# Codeigniter User Group Id Displaying Wrong In Database

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my codeigniter database I have 2 tables called `user` and `user_group`. When I create new user I need it to be able to get the first id from `user_group` which is `administrator`. And the user_group_id for administrator is 1

It currently gets the second row which is user_group_id number '10'

**Problem Can Not Get The First Row ID Of User Group**

Here is my insert model

```
public function insert() {
  $password = $this->input->post('password');
  $username = $this->input->post('username');
  $email = $this->input->post('email');

  $data = array(
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $this->hash($password),
    'status' => "1",
    'ip' => $this->input->ip_address(),
    'user_group_id' => $this->db->insert_id(),
    'date_added' => mdate('%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s', now())
  );

  $this->db->set($data);
  $this->db->insert('user');
  return $this->db->insert_id('user_id');
}
```

Comment: And your question is? (a location you most likely have an error is `$this->db->insert_id()`)

Comment: Updated post. Problem Can Not Get The First Row ID Of User Group

Comment: Solution: Get that ID first. In your code it's not clear where you do that, where you validate it (always validate) and then the database structure is missing so we can not tell you how to fetch it if. `$this->db->insert_id()` is dynamic and most likely not holding the correct ID - only by chance but that chance is very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very little.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the user id as per normal and I hard coded the user_group_id this is how I did it below on my Model.

```
public function user() {
            $this->db->escape($username = $this->input->post('username'));
            $this->db->escape($email = $this->input->post('email'));
            $this->db->escape($salt = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 9));
            $this->db->escape($password = sha1($salt . sha1($salt . sha1($this->input->post('password')))));    

            $data = array(
                  'username' => $username,
                  'password' => $password,
                  'status' => "1",
                  'salt' => $salt,
                  'ip' => $this->input->ip_address(),
                  'user_group_id' => "1",
                  'date_added' => mdate('%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s', now())
            );

            $this->db->set($data);
            $this->db->insert('user');
            return $this->db->insert_id();
      }
```